# Azure Databricks Multi-task jobs and workflows. Simulate on completion status

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows

Currently, we are investigating how to effectively incorporate databricks latest feature for orchestration of tasks - Multi-task Jobs.

The default behaviour is that a downstream task would not be executed if the previous one has failed for some reason.

So the question is: Is it currently possible to have an onComplete status (similar to those in Azure Data Factory or SQL Server Integration services-SSIS) that regardsless of the task success or failure we can continue with the workflow and execute the next tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now it's not possible, but you can just surround your code with try/catch, so if error is thrown then catch block won't propagate exception further, and task won't be marked as failed.

Comment: Hi @alex-ott, sure this would catch the error and allow the run to continue if we have something like this built-in:
try: 
  do_something() 
except Exception as e: err=repr(e), so catching the error inside the err variable, however I would never get notified about my task failing by an email, which is definitely something I would like to have. Perhaps a workaround would then be having to log the results of the err variable and receive daily notification set up by some other process or service like Azure Monitor.

Comment: Yes. You can potentially post into log analytics or just send email from catch block. I recommend to pass your requirements to customer success engineer or solution architect associated with your account  - they can pass requirements to developers